# Restore "Access the user's profile" API Access

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I deleted the "Access the user's profile" (which has access to "openid" and "offline_access" permissions) under API access in my Azure AD B2C application, and now I can't find a way to restore it. I cannot delete the app and create a new one.

Microsoft's documentation specifies that they are granted by default and can be removed but they don't mention how to restore them:

`By default, applications are granted the ability to access the user's profile via the "openid” permission, and generate refresh tokens via the "offline_access" permission. These can be removed if you do not want your client application to have this functionality.`

[image: Screenshot showing the row that I deleted]

How can I restore this?

Comment: Based on this github issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35323 , it is not possible to restore the default api access settings. A support ticket to microsoft may help. @wise.potato, if you have created the issue, you can write a short answer refering this ticket, so that other users with the same problem find the answer faster.

Comment: Thank you, I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this [github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35323), there is no way to recover those scopes currently, you have to file a support ticket so that Microsoft restores them manually.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled alot with this. Unfortunately Microsoft Azure has a bug.

But there is a workaround for this that I found after two days of effort:

1. Go to App registration
2. Select your application
3. Go to Authentication -> Redirect URI
4. Add new URL (eg. http://localhost:8000)

This will re-instate *"Access the user's profile"* in API Access in Azure AD B2C.

Now you can select below scopes;

- Acquire an `id_token` for users(openid)
- Acquire a `refresh_token` for users(offline_access)

and this will add *"Access the user's profile"* in API Access window.

Hope this will help you. There is no need of deleting existing app.

Comment: I just tried your workaround but it didn't work. Thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: I simulated 4 times, it worked, if you want I can share my screen and explain